# Support for "dangling" textures in a GLTF file? i.e., textures that are in the file but aren't connected to a material

Tags: gltf

What I mean with "dangling" textures: In Blender, it would look something like this:
[image]

The other two textures aren't really connected to any nodes, but they're still there, and they're still associated with that particular material.

My current approach is creating multiple materials with "_1", "_2" suffixes, and the "_2" are unused, but it's not exactly elegant, IMO. The material variants extension isn't really what I'm looking for, either - since I still need to define a separate material for each variant, it's almost the same as the numbered suffix method that I currently have.

Does the GLTF spec support something like this?

Answer (score 0):

The glTF spec supports textures and images included in the file that are not referenced by any particular material, yes.  However, the Blender glTF exporter will not include dangling nodes (as you've shown here) in the exported glTF file, so you can't create them directly like that.

I would recommend taking a second look at [glTF Material Variants](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html#gltf-variants).  It may appear to be a lot of extra bulk in your Blender project, but you can easily copy/paste the materials and assign new textures.  When these materials export to glTF, the actual material definition is only a couple lines of JSON, so having multiple copies of it is nearly free.  Having multiple images together in the GLB is far more expensive (in space taken) than the duplicate material definitions.  Give it a try and check out the file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The glTF format supports "dangling" textures, but (unlike Blender's shader node graph view) they won't be associated with a particular material. I don't think Blender exports unused textures, but one way to add them later would be:

```
npm install --global @gltf-transform/cli

gltf-transform merge input.glb cloth_diffuse.png brick_diffuse.png output.glb
```

glTF does not provide any way to associate a texture with a material, without also defining *how* the texture is associated with the material — e.g. as base color, emissive, normal, or other material texture slot. For that you'd probably want to consider approaches like:

- Material Variants
- Extras ("Custom Properties" in Blender) referencing textures or materials by name
- Custom glTF extensions